# Need htaccess redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect below urls using htaccess

`http://abc.domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com/pos`

`http://xyz.domain.com/weighing-scales.php`  to `http://www.domain.com/weighing`

I tried using below directive in .htaccess file but it is not working. Kindly help

```
Redirect 301 http://abc.domain.com http://www.domain.com/pos
Redirect 301 http://xyz.domain.com/weighing-scales.php http://www.domain.com/weighing-scales
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 not found error?

Comment: Yes.."The page you requested cannot be found!". There is a custom 404 Page.

Comment: The second argument of redirect directive is **url-path** not the full url. Try removing the hostname from Both redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....  Can u kindly show me an example of that?  can i write like this.. Redirect 301 %{HTTP_HOST} abc.domain.com /pos

Comment: No, you cant! %{HTTP_HOST} is part of a diffrent module (mod-rewrite) and you can not use it in Redirect directive.

Comment: Redirect 301 abc.domain.com /pos is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```bash
RewriteEngine on

#--abc.domain.com/ => domain.com/pos--# 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/pos [L,R]
#--xyz.domain.com/weighing-scales\.php =>domain.com/weighing--# 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^weighing-scales\.php$ http://domain.com/weighing [L,R]
```