# Redirect “test/oldfile.htm” to “test/new.htm” using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am Using XAMPP Server.

I have a folder or project named test in my htdocs.

I want to redirect user to redirect to newfile.htm when user access oldfile.htm direcly using htaccess.

I wrote below code in mine htaccess file but its not working

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile.htm
```

Kindly Guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need htaccess redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654713/need-htaccess-redirection)

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654713/need-htaccess-redirection?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect directive is part of apache alias module. You don't need to write **RewriteEngine on** to use Redirect. The reason why your Redirect failed is because you are a relative  test path, you need to specify a full/absolute path  in Redirect.

```
Redirect 301 /test/oldfile.html /test/newfile.html
```

should work. If the problem presists, Try clearing your browser cache and make sure you dont have other conflicting redirects in htaccess.